# CDATA not rendering properly ]]> appearing at the end

Tags: html, xml, cdata

so I am trying to render some CDATA being returned from an xml service.
The data being returned is of the form:

```
   <Characteristic>
              <name>What to do what to say</ns32:name>
              <value>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;br&gt; Line1 &lt;/br&gt; Line2]]&gt;</value>
           <orderCharacteristic>
```

I then display this value in a ftl file using the following code:

```
<#if Characteristic.name="What to do what to say">
    <#assign whatToSay=orderCharacteristic.value>
</#if>
${whatToSay}
```

Noramlly it should be displayed as:

```
 Line1
 Line 2
```

However whenever I am trying to display the value it is appearing as:

```
    Line1
    Line 2]]>
```

Not sure why I am getting the ]]> at the end, if I remove it, the xml is read fine, and the message is also displayed properly, but what is bugging me is the why.

Comment: How is the source XML generated? Is that something you can control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what's being written into your HTML is

```
<![CDATA[<br> Line1 </br> Line2]]>
```

HTML doesn't understand CDATA blocks like that so it interprets it as

```
<![CDATA[<br>   -- bogus comment
Line1           -- text
<br>            -- line break
Line2]]>        -- text
```

Comment: More exactly, CDATA sections are not recognized by HTML parsers, which are used when a document is served with a content type like `text/html`. When served with an XHTML content type, CDATA sections are recognized as per XML specifications (but then you have problem with old versions of IE).

Comment: So what would be the proper way to end this. Line2 and ]]> have a space in between by the way. Does HTML understand ]]> as the end to CDATA?

Comment: @Punkeshwar - The CDATA block does work at all in HTML (or as Jukka correctly puts it, is not recognized by HTML parsers) and that includes the `]]>` bit. You will need to find a way to strip off the CDATA start and end somehow before sending it to the browser. (Or use an XHTML media type as per Jukka's comment)

Comment: @Alohci Since I can't control the xml tags that it comes in, I think its better that I use a bit of String control before displaying the text. Thanks all